# deploying on a iOS 6.1 device with Xcode 4.3.2 - iOS 5 SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5, deployment

I want to deploy my iOS 5.1 BASE SDK project, (with Xcode 4.3.2) on a iOS 6 device. I am fully aware of current solutions regarding this issue;

**NOTE:** I don't want to work on the simulator because I am working on a MBPRO 13' and the iPad simulator won't fit to my screen. Since I cannot seem to downgrade the iPad, this is what I have to deal with.

**Option A:** Upgrading to Xcode 4.5

Disadvantage

- A lot of people having issues while having multiple versions of Xcode and I am in far depth with a current project. So I can not risk this.

**Option B:** Creating an Archive file and distributing it as an IPA file. Then sending it to the device via iTunes.

Disadvantage

- This option seems to be the most fitting option since I do not have to change anything. But the problem is it takes about 3-4 mins to create the IPA, and send it to the device via iTunes.

I am asking for any workarounds for the disadvantages of option A or B.

- Is there a solid way to keep both versions of Xcodes and switch between them with 100% security and not break any of Xcodes?
- Is there such an automation which will retrieve the IPA and put it to device for option B?
- Or is there an option C which will help me solve this issue?

Since this should be a common problem, there should be an easy solution to this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: Is there a solid way to keep both versions of Xcodes and switch between them with 100% security and not break any of Xcodes?

A: Yes, just install them in different places.  I regularly have released versions of Xcode installed in `/Applications` and Developer Preview versions installed in `~/Applications`.

Q: Is there such an automation which will retrieve the IPA and put it to device for option B?

A: I don't think so, so you could write it yourself.  You could also use TestFlight.

Q: Or is there an option C which will help me solve this issue?

A: Update to Xcode 4.6 and just work like you should.

Also note that the iPhone Simulator can be scaled to fit your Desktop; I often have to when testing against Retina iDevices on my 15" MBP.